# FCM is not working after changing the package name

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to develop an application that will show notifications using Firebase. Firebase notification was working fine on my device but its not working on other devices but after changing the package name, **FCM** is not working anymore. I try to add same package name in **Firebase Console** but still the same issue

here's my code

**Manifest.xml**

```
   <service
             android:name=".Model.Services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
   <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/icon" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt**

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
private var mNotificationManager: NotificationManager? = null
private var mBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder? = null
var NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001"
var notificationPref:SharedPreferences? = null

override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage?) {
    Log.d("FirebaseMessage", "message")
    notificationPref = getSharedPreferences("Notification" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    message?.data?.isNotEmpty()?.let {
        Log.d("FirebaseMessage", "Message data payload: " + message.data)
    }
    message?.notification?.let {
        Log.d("FirebaseMessage", "Message Notification Body: ${it.body}")
        val editor = notificationPref?.edit()
        var count = notificationPref?.getInt("notification_count" , 0)
        Log.d("FirebaseMessage", "Message Notification count: $count")
        count = count?.plus(1)
        editor?.putInt("notification_count" , count!!)
        editor?.apply()
        sendNotification(it.body)
    }

}

private fun sendNotification(notification: String?) {
    val resultIntent = Intent(this, Dashboard::class.java)
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

    val resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )

    mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    mBuilder!!.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    mBuilder!!.setContentTitle("Notification")
        .setContentText(notification)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)

    mNotificationManager = this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val notificationChannel =
            NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance)
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
        notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
        notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
        assert(mNotificationManager != null)
        mBuilder!!.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
        mNotificationManager!!.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }
    assert(mNotificationManager != null)
    mNotificationManager!!.notify(0 /* Request Code */, mBuilder!!.build())
}
}
```

Comment: have u download the new Google-service json file after updating package name in Firebase console ?

Comment: yes i did but still same

Answer (score 4):

Go to [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com).

Select your project

Download `google-service.json`

> > **[How to download ?](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en)**
> >
> > Get a config file for your Android app
> >     To download a config file for an Android app:
> >     Sign in to Firebase and open your project.
> >
> > Click the Settings icon and select Project settings.
> >     In the Your apps card, select the package name of the app you need a config file for from the list.
> >
> > Click google-services.json.

copy `google-services.json` file into the app/ folder of your Android Studio project.

FCM is based on  `google-service.json` configuration.

For more details [Set up a Firebase Cloud Messaging client app on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

**Note : After all setup. 
Delete `build` folder and rebuild project.**

Comment: @HussainAbbas have you read note ?, Because this issue i already faced. And try to solve using above steps, If then also not solved this issue, then create new project in firebase console with latest package name

Comment: Device version ?

Comment: add this code if you are working latest android version

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

Comment: this one too.. i just edit my question you can see it there

Comment: firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled = true

Comment: @HussainAbbas, i tested on my code is working dear, please look into the code, may be you will get some mistake.

Comment: bro my code is working fine i just create a new project with same code as MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt

Comment: Because i tried.. and working perfect... Happy for you

Comment: bro its working when i try to **TEST ON DEVICE** but its not working when i send the message to all the devices

Comment: do you have another solution or an example?

Comment: Rebuilding the project saved my day, Thanks