# flutter firebase cloud messaging

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have 2 projects in my firebase : `testProject` and `mainProject` (let's call them like that)
So I implemented the firebase messaging using [this](https://medium.com/comerge/implementing-push-notifications-in-flutter-apps-aef98451e8f1) tutorial and it works with the json from `testProject` but after I change to `mainProject` json, my emulator doesn't receive the notifications. I think this is really weird because in both projects I added the app and I only changed the json.

Do you know why this happens?

this is my code:

```
class MyAppRC extends StatelessWidget {
  static final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pushNotificationService = PushNotificationService(_firebaseMessaging);
    pushNotificationService.initialise();
    return MaterialApp(),
      home: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}
```

`Push_notification_service`

```
class PushNotificationService {
  final FirebaseMessaging _fcm;

  PushNotificationService(this._fcm);

  Future initialise() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
    }
    String token = await _fcm.getToken();
    debugPrint("FirebaseMessaging token: $token");

    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Ps. for more details please ask.

Comment: After changing the generated file from firebase, did you uninstall/reinstall the app?

Comment: @SoonSantos yeah I did that

Comment: The code seems fine, if it worked once it means it is working. Are you changing `google-services.json` for android? Or are u doing it for iOS, or maybe both? Hard to tell, try to double-check if you wrote the same package name in both firebase projects.

Comment: @SoonSantos only now just for android.. Yeah I have the same packages... I even added the app again in the projects

Comment: I am not sure how to help, but if you say everything is the same in both projects. Try [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53775173/8383332) and make sure you deleted the build folder.

Comment: thx I'll try @SoonSantos

Comment: Just for curiosity, did you solve your problem?

Comment: I did that but now I get another error...


Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.

Comment: @SoonSantos here is the link to my new question about the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236521/error-when-communicating-with-the-firebase-installations-server-api